# Only seeing a single step in tensorboard when running tf.estimator.train for 100 steps

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a custom estimator that is constructed via my own custom `model_fn`. I'd like to run `train` on it and see a datapoint in tensorboard for every step. However, I only see a single datapoint for every call, regardless of the number of steps. Here is how I construct and train my estimator:

```
    estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn,
        params=params,
        model_dir='/mnt/c/stuff/model')

    def make_input_fn():
        return tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
            x=signal,
            y=labels,
            batch_size=len(signal),
            num_epochs=None,
            shuffle=False)

    estimator.train(input_fn=make_input_fn(), steps=100)
```

When I execute this function, regardless of what I put in for the `steps` parameter, I end up with a single datapoint in tensorboard:

[image: single datapoint in tensorflow]

I have written a small test to confirm my use of  `tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn` is correct (it should return the same Dataset indefinitely), and have also tried varying the `steps` parameter to the `train` call. Increasing `steps` slows down the amount of time it takes to run `train`, but I still only get a single datapoint.

If I run the `train` function 3 times, I get 3 datapoints in tensorboard:

[image: 3 datapoints in tensorboard]

What is happening here, and how can I get tensorboard to show me a datapoint for every training step, as opposed to just every call to `train`?

Comment: The x axis seems to indicate that plot is not with respect to time steps.

Comment: @vijaym the x axis is 0 for the first call, and increments by the number of training steps for every subsequent call. So basically it seems to be the value of `global_step` _before_ the call.

Comment: Comparing both the graph,  indicates that the x axis for the first graph is actually the value of x and not the time steps. Is the value of x 1 at every call?