# TensorBoard scalar summaries are single data points. How to fix?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

[image: tf.train.MonitoredSession]

I am logging using the `tf.summary.scalar` method AND with `tf.train.LoggingTensorHook` for some tensors. This is with the `tf.estimator.Estimator` framework.

The `tf.train.LoggingTensorHook` stuff is not even showing up AFAIK. The other stuff is showing but apparently without time steps.

Graphs and everything else (weights) look ok in tensorboard.

UPDATE: it looks like calling train multiple times results in a graph. Is there something about `steps` and `every_n_iter` that do not interact as expected?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

m = 10000
n = 5
X = np.random.randn(m, n)
A = np.random.randn(n)
y = X.dot(A) + np.random.randn(m) * 0.1

batch_size = 1024

def input_fn(batch_size):
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(X=X, y=y))
    ds = ds.repeat(-1)
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
    return ds

def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    X = features['X']
    y = features['y']
    l = X
    for i, k in enumerate([32, 16, 16]):
        l = tf.layers.dense(inputs=l, units=k, name=f'l_{i}', activation=tf.nn.tanh)
    some_thing = tf.reduce_sum(l, axis=1, name='some_thing')
    l = tf.layers.dense(inputs=l, units=1, name='l_final')
    predictions = tf.squeeze(l, axis=-1)
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, predictions, weights=1.0)
    metric_ops = {"mse": tf.metrics.mean_squared_error(labels=y, predictions=predictions)}
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op, eval_metric_ops=metric_ops)
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        predictions = {}
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=predictions)
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=metric_ops)
    raise Exception('should not hit this')

model = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=model_fn,
        model_dir='/tmp/junk',
        config=None,
        params=dict(),
        warm_start_from=None
        )

tensors_to_log = dict(some_thing='some_thing')
logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=10)

train_input_fn = lambda: input_fn(batch_size)
test_input_fn = lambda: input_fn(batch_size)

train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=train_input_fn, hooks=[logging_hook], max_steps=100)
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=test_input_fn, hooks=[logging_hook])
out = tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(model, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

UPDATE: This one does not show in tensorboard until the end of the run and then it only shows one point too.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
# tf.enable_eager_execution()
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

m = 10000
n = 5
X = np.random.randn(m, n)
A = np.random.randn(n)
y = X.dot(A) + np.random.randn(m) * 0.1

steps = 1000
batch_size = 1024

def input_fn(repeat, batch_size):
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(X=X, y=y))
    ds = ds.repeat(repeat)
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
    return ds

def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    X = features['X']
    y = features['y']
    l = X
    for i, k in enumerate([32, 16, 16]):
        l = tf.layers.dense(inputs=l, units=k, name=f'l_{i}', activation=tf.nn.tanh)
    some_thing = tf.reduce_sum(l, axis=1, name='some_thing')
    l = tf.layers.dense(inputs=l, units=1, name='l_final')
    predictions = tf.squeeze(l, axis=-1)
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, predictions, weights=1.0)
    metric_ops = {"mse": tf.metrics.mean_squared_error(labels=y, predictions=predictions)}

    tf.summary.scalar('summary_loss', loss) # plot a dist across the batch
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op, eval_metric_ops=metric_ops)
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        predictions = {}
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=predictions)
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=metric_ops)
    raise Exception('should not hit this')

model = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=model_fn,
        model_dir='/tmp/junk',
        config=None,
        params=dict(),
        warm_start_from=None
        )

tensors_to_log = dict(some_thing='some_thing')
logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=10)

train_input_fn = lambda: input_fn(steps, batch_size)
test_input_fn = lambda: input_fn(steps, batch_size)

train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=train_input_fn, hooks=[logging_hook], max_steps=None)
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=test_input_fn, hooks=[logging_hook])
out = tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(model, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

Comment: I now think there is some flushing setting with the logger. If I wait long enough it eventually starts printing things.

Comment: Please add the code about the summary part. So others can help you figure out.

Comment: I've added a bit of code but it is not the code. Basically the varioius train and train_and_eval methods in tensorflow seem to rely on the input_fn batch ending to print. 

Also the hook stuff is the stuff that is *not logging at all* and that is straight from the examples. 

If I repeatedly call train it plots more points. 

Is there a *complete* simple example that logs the !@#$ out of everything in tensorflow/models? I only see over-filled incomplete stuff there.

Comment: And I am looking for logging of a) metrics b) summaries c) hooks d) matplotlib figures. That is what I deem to be complete. It looks like it is possible but there are many flavours.

Comment: `LoggingTensorHook` has nothing to do with TensorBoard. Do you want to show summaries every 10 steps instead of 100?

Comment: Yeah something like that, or I would like to understand why it is not plotting at all sometimes as well. I'm updating the code to include a complete very simple example with random data.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like NOTHING hits tensorboard when max_steps=100 but one point does when max_steps=101. So there is some default logging rate there that I am not over-riding. I am expecting the logging hook every_n_iter=10 to over-ride that but that is not happening.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836214/only-seeing-a-single-step-in-tensorboard-when-running-tf-estimator-train-for-100

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a very similar problem. and I was surprised that the solution is very simple. Close TensorBoard and initiated again, and wait for a few minutes. it takes time to catch up. For some reason, if you initiate TensorBoard during the training it will stuck. I hope this will help. 
I was running the code on google cloud

```
from google.datalab.ml import TensorBoard
TensorBoard().start('gs://{}/directoy_where_my_models_are'.format(BUCKET))
```

[image]

Comment: In my case "a few minutes" turned out to be 2 hours. But in the end, I just needed to wait. (I restarted a few times, but I can't really tell if that helped or not.)